# Slick error: "value create is not a member of com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.DDL"

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I'd like to be able to use the H2Driver for tests and the SQLServerDriver in production.  Therefore I've structured my classes like this:

```
class SomeClass @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
{
   val driver = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile].driver
   import driver.api._
   //import SQLServerDriver.api._  fixes problem, but it ties my code to a particular driver

   def blah = oneOfMyTables.schema.create //compile error: "value create is not a member of com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.DDL"
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the error "value create is not a member of com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.DDL".  it seems like the implicits are not being properly imported.

I do not get this error if I import SQLServerDriver.api._.

I'm using slick 3.1.1 and slick-extensions 3.1.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe this is impossible given how Slick is designed. [edit:] Implicits are a compile-time construct, not a run-time construct, and their resolution therefore can't be delayed until the application runs.

Comment: Your explanation about implicits makes sense.  If there's really no way to use different drivers in test than in prod that's incredibly frustrating. I'm sure the lightbend response is to use a dummy repository in test, but I would prefer to exercise the repository as part of the test.

Comment: I have the exact same frustration. I'd really like to see a mock driver library come out of the Slick project. I've gotten halfway toward writing one myself.

Comment: I've found a way to use different drivers in test and production!  I setup a repository like this: class MyRepository @Inject() (val profile: JdbcProfile){import profile.api._}.  Everywhere I use that repository, I import repo.profile.api._ to get the api.  (It seems like you should be able to just inject JdbcProfile all over the place, but I ran into issues described at the following link doing that:  https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1638)

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to try that out.